# Feynman Mass vs. Charge Movement

Tags: conservation-laws

In *The Character of Physical Law*, Feynman presents a brief proof that charge conservation must be local. I had some confusion over local vs. global conservation, but thought I understood after reading the discussion [in this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190983/feynmans-layman-proof-of-local-charge-conservation).

Later on in the same lecture/chapter, Feynman says

> A mass, in a box, cannot just disappear from one position and move over to another position all by itself. That is nothing to do with conservation of the mass; you still have the mass, just moved from one place to another. **Charge could do this, but not a mass**.   [emphasis mine]

Video of the same is [here](https://youtu.be/r_IfV9fkBhk?t=51m57s).

It seems to me like Feynman is contradicting what he just proved and saying charge in fact can disappear and reappear without moving through the space in between, indicating I have some misunderstanding.

What is Feynman saying charge could do that mass cannot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Here, Richard Feynman is contrasting the properties of charge and mass. A charge can move down a wire or something without affecting the angular momentum. A mass cannot move like that without affecting the angular momentum. So he's saying "mass" has a different kind of physical property than "charge".

If you watch the succeeding part of the video and think about the point he's trying to make, it makes more sense.