# Noether's 2nd Theorem and Local Gauge Identities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

I am trying to derive the so called Gauge Identities:
\begin{equation}
D_\nu\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi} = 0
\end{equation}
Where $D_\nu$ is an operator involving derivatives and $\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}$ are the usual Euler-Lagrange equations.

So far I have taken the following local field transformation:
\begin{equation}
\bar{\delta}\phi(x) = \varphi_\nu\lambda^\nu(x)\simeq \varphi_\nu\lambda^\nu + \varphi^\mu_\nu\partial_\mu\lambda^\nu
\end{equation}

And varied the action:
\begin{align}
\bar{\delta}S &= \int d^4x~\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}\bar{\delta}\phi + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\partial_\mu\bar{\delta}\phi\right)\\
&= \int d^4x~\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}\left(\varphi_\nu^0\lambda^\nu + \varphi_\nu^\rho\partial_\rho\lambda^\nu\right) + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\partial_\mu\left(\varphi_\nu^0\lambda^\nu + \varphi_\nu^\rho\partial_\rho\lambda^\nu\right)\right)\\
&\text{Integrate the second term by parts to get}\\
&= \int d^4x~\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}\left(\varphi_\nu^0\lambda^\nu + \varphi_\nu^\rho\partial_\rho\lambda^\nu\right) - \partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\left(\varphi_\nu^0\lambda^\nu + \varphi_\nu^\rho\partial_\rho\lambda^\nu\right)\right)\\
&= \int d^4x~\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi} - \partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\right)\right]\varphi_\nu^0\lambda^\nu + \left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi} - \partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\right)\right]\varphi_\nu^\rho\partial_\rho\lambda^\nu\\
&\text{Again integrate the second term by parts to get}\\
&= \int d^4x~\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi} - \partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\right)\right]\varphi_\nu^0\lambda^\nu - \partial_\rho\left(\left[\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi} - \partial_\mu\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\partial_\mu\phi}\right)\right]\varphi_\nu^\rho\right)\lambda^\nu\\
&=\int d^4x~\partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu(\lambda)
\end{align}

Recognising this stuff in the integral as the operator $D_\nu$, I get the following:

\begin{equation}
\int d^4x ~\left(\partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu(\lambda) - \lambda^\nu D_\nu\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}\right) = 0
\end{equation}

What I don't understand is how to now see that $D_\nu\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi} = 0$ for arbitrary $\lambda$.

What if I choose a parameter that doesn't make $\mathcal{J}$ vanish on the surface for example?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66092/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets denote the spacetime manifold by $M$. For any localized function $\lambda$ without support at the boundaries of spacetime, the first term in your last equation is vanishing, since it can be recast into a boundary integral, i.e. 
$$\int_M \partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu(\lambda)=\int_{\partial M}d\Sigma_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu(\lambda)=0$$
Now take a closed subregion $N\subset M$ and consider functions $\lambda$ on $M$ such that they are arbitrary on $N$ while vanishing outside. Using the above argument in your last equation implies that 
\begin{equation}
\int_N d^4x ~\lambda^\nu D_\nu\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}= 0
\end{equation}
Since $\lambda$ is arbitrary on $N$, we find that $D_\nu\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}= 0$ on $N$. Repeating this argument for a sequence of patches $N_i$, which altogether cover $M$, we conclude that $D_\nu\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}= 0$ on the whole manifold $M$. Would you agree?