# What is the publication through which Zinn-Justin published what has come to be known as the "Zinn-Justin equation"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, history, specific-reference

does anybody know which publication contains the introduction of what has come to known as the [Zinn-Justin equation](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Zinn-Justin_equation)?

Answer (score 5):

> J. Zinn-Justin, *Renormalization of gauge theories,* Bonn lectures 1974.
>
> Published in *Trends in Elementary Particle Physics,* Lecture Notes in Physics 37 (1975) 1-39, H. Rollnik and K. Dietz eds., Springer Verlag, Berlin. ISBN 978-3-540-07160-0.

The [Zinn-Justin (ZJ) equation](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Zinn-Justin_equation) itself can be found in several versions within *Chapter III: Gauge symmetries.*

Interestingly, Zinn-Justin introduces an "antiproduct" notation $F\ast G$ in eq. (55). The [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) "antibracket" from 1981 can then be written as
$$(F,G)~=~F\ast G - (-1)^{(|F|+1)(|G|+1)}G\ast F. $$
The ZJ equation is equivalent to the classical BV master equation $(S,S)=0,$ cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/61708/2451).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a seminar given by Zinn-Justin himself, in which he details the history of this equation. He states he first presented it at the Bonn summer school 1974. You will find all the references you seek.

> Renormalization of gauge theories and master equation. Jean Zinn-Justin. [*Mod. Phys. Lett. A* **14**, 1227 (1999)](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0217732399001322), [arXiv:hep-th/9906115](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9906115).

Answer (score 2):

Well, as per the link in your question, that would appear to be

> [*Trends in Elementary Particle Physics*](https://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540071600), Lecture Notes in Physics vol. 37, pp. 1-39, H. Rollnik and K. Dietz, eds. (Springer Verlag, Berlin, 1975).